# Javascript Event Bubbling

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

I have this setup

```
<div onclick="SomeEvent">
    <input type=checkbox value=1>1
    <input type=checkbox value=2>2
    <input type=checkbox value=3>3
</div>
```

The problem when the user click on the checkboxes I don't want the SomeEvent fired.

In the some event I do have the line
"event.stopPropagation();"
but that seems to do nothing at all.

Comment: `SomeEvent` would have to be `SomeEvent()` if used in an inline event listener (which shouldn't be used).

Answer (score 7):

In the event *bubbling* model, the event propagation is from the inner elements to the outer elements.

This means that the *event.stopPropagation();* should be in the inputs' events instead of the div.

```html
<div onclick="SomeEvent">
  <input type=checkbox value=1 onclick="stopPropagation()">1
  <input type=checkbox value=2 onclick="stopPropagation()>2
  <input type=checkbox value=3 onclick="stopPropagation()>3
</div>
```

Now the Javascript code:

```js
function stopPropagation() {
  //... do something.
  //stop propagation:
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true; //IE
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); //other browsers
}
```

More info: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

**EDIT**: The above was a quick way to show how the bubbling model works, but a better answer to solve this problem using JQuery would be:

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" /> 3
</div>
```

Now the Javascript code:

```js
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
  //do something
});

$('#mydiv input').click(function(e) {
  //stop propagation:
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true; //IE
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); //other browsers
});
```

Comment: I don't like that i have to add code to the checkbox to prevent the click from happening.

Comment: This was just a quick example, but if you are using JQuery the right way to do this would be to use something like $('#element1 input').click(stopPropagation());

I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Change the inline onclick to this:

```
onclick="SomeEvent(this, event)"
```

Then in `SomeEvent`, do this:

```
function SomeEvent( el, event ) {
    var target = event.srcElement || event.target;

    if( el === target ) {
        // run your code
    }
}
```

This will only fire the code when you click on the `div` element itself, instead of a descendant.

If there are other descendants that should fire the handler, then do this:

```
function SomeEvent( el, event ) {
    var target = event.srcElement || event.target;

    if( target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'input' || !target.type || target.type !== 'checkbox' ) {
        // run your code
    }
}
```

This will fire the handler for any click except those on the checkboxes.

Comment: I like the potential this has since I can limit each event to one method. However I am using jquery to attach the event. In the attached event the event.target.id and the event.srcElementid is always blank. The this.id returns the proper id.