# How to access Event.target in IE9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, events, internet-explorer-9, dom

The HTML DOM object model defines an `Event` object [with a `target` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10637046/12597).

Looking at MSDN, Microsoft documents a [`target` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They also document [`srcElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as an alias of `target` from earlier versions of Internet Explorer:

> The **target** property is similar to [**srcElement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

---

So here i am in Internet Explorer, sitting at a `click` breakpoint:

```
<div class="day" onclick="divClick(this)">

function divClick(sender)
{
   var divCell = sender;
```

And at the **F12 Tools** console i can ask for the global `event` object:

```
>> event 
{
    actionURL : "",
    altKey : false,
    altLeft : false,
    behaviorCookie : 0,
    behaviorPart : 0,
    bookmarks : null,
    boundElements : {...},
    button : 0,
    buttonID : 0,
    cancelBubble : false
    ...
}
```

And i can ask for the `event.srcElement` object:

```
>> event.srcElement 
{
    align : "",
    noWrap : false,
    dataFld : "",
    dataFormatAs : "",
    dataSrc : "",
    currentStyle : {...},
    runtimeStyle : {...},
    accessKey : "",
    className : "header",
    contentEditable : "inherit"
    ...
}
```

But `event.target` is empty:

```
>> event.target
```

And if i *watch* `event`, there is no `target` property:

[image]

So how do i access the `target` property of an `event` object in Internet Explorer (9 (Document Mode: IE9 Standards (Browser Mode: IE9)))?

Comment: Have you considered letting a library such as jQuery do the dirty work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `event.target` in IE9, you'll need to use `addEventListener()`-method to assign eventhandler to the element.

```
<div id="day" class="day"></div>

document.getElementById('day').addEventListener('click',divClick,false);

function divClick(e){
   alert(e.target);
   divCell=this;
   :
}
```

In `divClick()` you can refer `day` simply using keyword `this`. Argument `e` contains a reference to the event-object itself.

BTW, in MSDN you can find maybe more suitable IE-documentation for [Web development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772401%28v=vs.85%29) instead of Windows development.

Comment: *"IF you want to use `event.target` is IE9, you'll need to use `addEventListener()`"* Is there any reference on this that i may read more about? i've scoured the IEBlog, but can find no mention - nor does the MSDN page on `event.target` mention it. i'd like to find the original description that says assigning `onclick` is "wrong".

Comment: Well... I'm sorry, I can't point you any exact reference, but this is what I've learn about IE9 by using it, and it works... `onclick` is not wrong, but in IE9 it's just reserved to act exactly like in older IE-versions.

Comment: @Teemu : Can I achieve the same in jQuery ??

Comment: @hitesh Yes, jQuery normalizes some `Event` properties (like `.target`), but you have to set listeners with jQuery.

Answer (score 13):

event.target ?

Do you need to check on it and assign that to a variable and use that instead ..

```
  var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
```

might be missing the point...

Comment: Since IE(9) says it supports `event.target`, i was hoping to use (just) `event.target`, but i don't *see* any `event.target`.

Answer (score 2):

Here goes for my investigation (tested in IE9, IE10 & Edge browser modes on IE11, IE8 unfortunately breaks jsFiddle). In IE9 mode (IE11) event.target was available as a local variable to the function, don't know if it differs from the real IE9.

You cannot access `event` in any browser with an inline function. The problem is that when you do

```
<element onclick="someFunc(this)">
```

and you pass `this` as parameter, **`this === event.target`** (or srcElement), namely a **`[HTML Object]`**, not an **`[Event Object]`**.

So in practice that means that this:

```
<div id="foo" onclick="alert(this)"></div>
```

is the same as:

```
// note that onclick perfectly works, you don't necessarily need addEventListener
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(e) { alert(e.target) } //or
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function(e) { alert(e.target) }, false);
```

So you access event target either directly inline as the parameter, either through javascript as the object parameter's `target || srcElement` property.
You can test the results for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/tg6FP/2/

**Note:** In case you attach inline, the position of your scripts is crucial (right before closing body tag)
**Note:** In case you attach inline, given that `event.target` is the 'root' of the object passed, you cannot access other event properties, like `event.type`.
**Note:** Be careful with IE Developer mode. I've known it to be deceiving (eg, not correctly displaying DOM content in the element tree until you click 'Edit as HTML')

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to archive this is by using:

```
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

- Avoid to use a ternary operator.

The way this works is because:

1. Test if `event.target` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) which if does not exist in that browser will evaluate to false.
2. If evaluates to false then it will move to the next operator which in this case is `event.srcElement`.

And with this you will end up with the first value that is present on the current browser where the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was not that you didn’t use `addEventListener()` (because old-school `.onclick`-assignment works as well). The problem was that `divClick` got `this` (which equals `eventobj.target`), but you want the entire `eventobj`.

In the following two cases you only get `eventobj.target` under the name of `this` and you have no access to the arguments passed to the onclick-handler.

```
<div id=xyz onclick="divClick(this);">
document.getElementById("xyz").onclick = function () { divClick(this); };
```

You get the entire `eventobj` as normal parameter with the following line:

```
document.getElementById("xyz").onclick = divClick;
```

This is how an event is launched on the xyz element in IE9+ and other browsers:

```
document.getElementById("xyz").onclick(eventobj)
```

Answer (score -2):

use:

```
var target = (event.target !== undefined)? event.target.name : event.srcElement.tagName;
```

then:

```
if ( target === 'A' || target === '...') {
    ...
}
```

OR:
simple use:

```
var target = event.srcElement.tagName;
```

tested on Chrome 35 :)