# React.js event delegation from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, dom-events

I'm trying to set event handler on some little complex html structure in react and facing trouble. Let's say we have something like this:

```
clickHdlr: function(e){
 console.info(e.target.dataset.src);
}

<div data-src={loopItem} onClick={this.clickHdlr}>
 <div>some icon</div>
 <div>some text</div>
 <div>some icon</div>
</div>
```

So in event handler I want to have `loopItem` value but unfortunately I can have it only when parent div is clicked directly, if child element is clicked `dataset.src` is undefined. Of course I can repeat `data-src` in each child but it is nonsense. Why react bubbling is reverted why can't I do event listener on parent and just stop propagate it to children.

Comment: I've found answer. I need to use just e.currentTarget instead of e.target

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documentation of html dom Event object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636834/documentation-of-html-dom-event-object)