# How to hide a DIV element when I click outside

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have a `div` and want to hide it when I click outside. My code is:

```
<div id="mydiv">The div must be above button</div>

    $('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#mydiv').fadeOut(300);
    });
```

But it is not working for me ...

**UPDATE**

Full code is presented below. When I click on a button it shows a `div` above, so I need to hide this `div` when I click outside.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/7/)

```
<div id="but" style="text-align: right;"><button type="button">Show Div!</button></div>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">The div must be above button</div>

$("#but button").click(function(){
  var pos = $(this).offset(),
      div = $("#mydiv");

  // Make it visible off-page so
  // we can measure it
  div.css({
    "display": "block",
    "border": "1px solid black",
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": -10000,
    "top": 0
  });

  // Move it where we want it to be
  div.css({
    "left": pos.left - 40,
    "top":  pos.top - div.height() - 10
  });
});

$('#myDiv').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#mydiv').fadeOut(300);
});
```

Comment: You should always avoid to bind anything to document when not required

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In javascript **click** is a [bubbling event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971675/1588233), it starts on a **div** and goes up to a **document**. When you stop an event propagation using a `stopPropagation()` function, a click on the document is not handled. So, to solve your problem just remove `e.stopPropagation()`.

[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/40/)

The best way is:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/41/)

> If I click on this div, how to make to click outside and hide this div
>   ?

Ok, let's imagine, that when you are clicking on a container with id "wrapperId", "myDiv" should be hidden:

```
$("#wrapperId").click(function(e){
  $('#mydiv').fadeOut(300);
})
```

if container is a document, you can use `$(document)` instead of `$("#wrapperId")`.

[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/42/)

> It is not working look what is happening: [jsbin.com/ilowij/7](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/7)

You should stop a click event propagation when you are clicking the button. Make these changes:

```
$("#but button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```

[DEMO 4](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/8/)

Comment: Yes this works, but if I click on this div, how to make to click outside and hide this div ?

Comment: Yes logicaly it must but it is not working look what is happening: http://jsbin.com/ilowij/7/

Comment: Add a 'e.stopPropagation()' function into click handler for $("#but button")

Comment: Is it possible when I click on this DIV dont close ? just if clicking outside would close ?

Comment: Yes, you should add stopPropagation() for a DIV click event. See this demo: http://jsbin.com/ilowij/10/

Answer (score 8):

Try with below code that checks event target

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.id!="mydiv"){  // if click is not in 'mydiv'
    $('#mydiv').hide(3000);
  }
});
```

Comment: hide with click in outside

Comment: Not a good idea to bind a click to the document since it's not required. The condition 'if(e.target.id!="mydiv")' looks terribly.

Answer (score 2):

Better than binding click event to document, you can use this kind of snippet:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7qBn7/)

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
    .css({outline:0})
    .focusout(function(){
         $(this).fadeOut(300);  
    }).focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why all that just use css3 target

```
<a href='#login'>Login</a>


<div id='login'>
  blah blah blah
</div>


css:

#login{width:400px;height:600px;background:#fff;margin:10%
       auto;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;
      }

now we will hide the login box by putting a class on it 

<div class='lightbox' id='login'>

</div>

css:

.lightbox{display:none;}
.lightbox:target{display:block;}
```

thats all the code dont need too use javascript

Comment: I cannot see to make it work. I would be useful to have a stackbliz example

Comment: I made the stackbliz and your code doesn't work to hide the panel: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-4my448?file=styles.css

Comment: I notice that this depends on the link to have the anchor. Not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution which is easy and it's even working recursive:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
<a href="#" id="link">Click me</a>
```

show or hide me by clicking

```
    (function($) {

  $("#link").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var div = $("#show_hide");

    // Make it visible off-page
    div.css({
      "display": "block"
    });

  });
$(document).click(function(e){
  $('#show_hide').fadeOut(300);
});
})(jQuery);
```

you can checkout this link for example..

check this http://jsfiddle.net/x5Env/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to capture the onclick event of the document. You know this click event happens outside the element that you are interested, then just return false.
I used this trick to hide a popup menu when a click outside the menu event fires.

Answer (score 0):

`$('html').click(function() {`
`$("div").css({"display": "none"});`
`});`
`$('.option').click(function(event){`
`event.stopPropagation();`
`});`

`$(".search").keyup(function(){`
    
`search=$(".search");`
`if(search.val()!= "" )`
`{`
`$("div").css({"display": "block"});`
`}`
`else`
`{`

`$("div").css({"display": "none"});`
`}`
`});`

```
  <input type="search" class="form-control search" name="search" autocomplete="off" >

  <div>

  </div>
```

this will help to hide

Answer (score -1):

try `.blur()`, and like this:

```
$('#mydiv').blur(function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Hope it help

Comment: It doesn't solve a problem. Originally the problem was related to a wrong using of a stopPropagation() function.