# Immune / Unclikable nested div

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a nested div like the code below

```
<body>
  <div style='border:solid 1px red' onclick='alert("hi")'>
  Hawaii
    <div style='border:solid 1px blue;margin:10px;' onclick="alert('haha');return false;">Aloha</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to show haha when div of aloha is clicked but not bubling to the Hawaii div onclick event, is there a way to achieve it?

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am aware of event bubbling, but is there a way to stop bubbling/cancel propagation for single element?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971601/javascript-event-bubbling among many others

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I am aware of event bubbling. But if I just want to disable bubbling for this element, is it possible?

Comment: I think you need to call stopPropagation (and whatever IE needs too) in your onclick handler after the call to alert.

Answer (score 1):

[event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation) does this in modern browsers.

In Internet Explorer before version 9 you need to set `event.cancelBubble = true` instead.

Example:

```
<div style='border:solid 1px blue;margin:10px;' onclick="alert('haha'); event.stopPropagation(); return false;">Aloha</div>
```

You can do a lot better if you avoid putting Javascript in HTML attributes.

Comment: I am aware of propagation and event bubbling, is it possible to cancel for one element but not all ?

Comment: @cherhan Yes, you call it (or set it for IE) in the event handler of the element you want to cancel it on.