# child div triggers parent div onmouseout event

Tags: html

I have div inside a div with the parent div have onmouseover and onmouseout functions

but when I hover on the child div the onmouseout function is triggerd which I don't want help?

```
<div onmouseover="alert("inside")" onmouseout="alert("outside")> <div></div> </div>
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sp9bD/2

the black div is inside the red one but the "outside" alert shows up

Comment: There is called event bubbling. Take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971601/javascript-event-bubbling

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').hover(function(e) {
    if (!(event.target.id === "inside")) {
        alert('inside');
    }
}, function () {
        alert('outside');

});
```

Try something like this using jQuery, here's the redone fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sp9bD/3/

Comment: still dosent work , when i hover over the child div an "outside" alert is still trigerd..

Comment: if you hover over the black div you won't get any alerts updated fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/sp9bD/5/

Comment: yea, but try entering from the red to the black the ouside will alert